# Trying to install tp-link Archer T1U adapter on Ubuntu

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, adapter, lsusb

I'm a complete novice when it comes to Ubuntu. I'm trying to install Archer T1U wireless adapter so I can acces my laptop wirelessly, but I can't install it. Results of `lsusb` are as follows:

```
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 093a:2510 Pixart Imaging, Inc. Optical Mouse
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 2357:0105  
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 090c:1000 Silicon Motion, Inc. - Taiwan (formerly Feiya Technology Corp.) Flash Drive
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 138a:003c Validity Sensors, Inc. VFS471 Fingerprint Reader
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 138a:003c Validity Sensors, Inc. VFS471 Fingerprint Reader
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I've tried

```
add-apt-repository ppa:hanipouspilot/rtlwifi
sudo apt update
sudo apt install mt7610u-dkms
```

But after it nothing happens, am I supposed to do something else after this?

Upgraded to 17.04, kernel version - 4.10.0-19-generic

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal command 'lsusb' Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: I've edited it to the best of my capability, im just not sure how to install its drivers for it to work.

Comment: What is the Ubuntu version, kernel version?

Comment: To add to the comment of @Pilot6, you can display the current kernel version with the command `uname -r`.

Comment: 4.8.0-36-generic

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get TP-Link Archer T1U USB wireless dongle working?](/q/791780/175814)

Comment: Thanks. Could you please [edit] your post, when you want to add information? It’s best to have everything relevant in one place. Additionally, comments may be deleted for various reasons. :-)

Comment: Will do, added info just there.

Comment: David, I followed the 3 commands on Pilot6's comment on the link you sent me, what should I do now?

Comment: I am afraid that driver in my answer won't work on 4.8.

Comment: Ah, any suggestions of what I can do?

Comment: Just upgraded to Ubuntu 17.04, if that helps in any way

Comment: If anybody has any suggestions of what I should do, let me know, im lost.